# Laravel Livewire SyntaxError - Unexpected token < in JSON and Internal Server Error 500

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have implemented livewire, serving as a dynamic table creation in my laravel application.

However, sometimes, there's this error appearing on the console and the livewire component stops working and I have to refresh the page.

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at index.js:58
```

Browsing through the `index.js`, you can see that the error comes from this line

```
...
if (this.isOutputFromDump(response)) {
    this.onError(message)
    this.showHtmlModal(response)
} else {
    this.onMessage(message, JSON.parse(response)) <-- this one
}
...
```

But I do not know why this happens or when would happen. It is completely randomly - sometimes happens when adding the first row, sometimes editing n-th row.

Second problem, again randomly, while adding rows or editing existing rows, there's a popup iframe of livewire that just tells it's a 500 error - internal server error.

This is the error on the console

```
javascript?v=1631258186:1173 POST http://domain/livewire/message/items-table 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And this is the trace from the network request:

```
Request URL: http://domain/livewire/message/items-table Request Method: POST Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

And this is the request payload:
[image: request payload]

This is the full code of the component items-table:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ItemsTable extends Component
{
public $data = null;

public $totalPrice = 0, $includeDiscount = 0, $subTotal = 0, $discountPrice = 0;

public $itemsTable = [];

public function addRow()
{
    if (!empty($this->itemsTable)) {
        if (end($this->itemsTable)['part_subtotal'] == "" || end($this->itemsTable)['part_qty'] == "" || end($this->itemsTable)['part_price'] == "" || end($this->itemsTable)['part_name'] == "") {
            $this->emit('itemEmpty');
            return;
        } else {
            $this->emit('itemNotEmpty');
        }
    }
    $this->itemsTable[] = [
        'part_no' => '',
        'part_name' => '',
        'part_qty' => '',
        'part_price' => '',
        'part_subtotal' => '',
    ];
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('focus-new-partno', ['id'=>array_key_last($this->itemsTable)]);
}
public function formatEur($currency)
{
    $currency = floatval($currency);
    return number_format($currency, 2, '.', ',');
}
public function deleteItem($id)
{
    unset($this->itemsTable[$id]);
    $this->itemsTable = array_values($this->itemsTable);
    $this->reCalculate();
}

public function reCalculate()
{
    $this->totalPrice = 0;
    foreach($this->itemsTable as $index => $data) {
        if($data['part_price'] > 1000000 || $data['part_qty'] > 1000000) {
            $this->totalPrice = 0;
            $data['part_subtotal'] = 0;
            $this->emit('maxLengthLimit');
            return;
        }
        $this->totalPrice += (float)$data['part_price']*(float)$data['part_qty'];
        $this->itemsTable[$index]['part_subtotal'] = $this->formatEur((float)$data['part_price'] * (float)$data['part_qty']);
    }
    if($this->includeDiscount == 1) {
        if($this->discountPrice > $this->totalPrice) {
            $this->discountPrice = $this->totalPrice;
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('discount-too-high', ['maxDiscount' => $this->totalPrice]);
            $this->reCalculate();
        } else {
            $this->subTotal = $this->totalPrice;
            $this->totalPrice = $this->subTotal - filter_var($this->discountPrice, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        }
    } else {
        $this->discountPrice = 0;
    }
}

public function mount()
{
    if($this->data == null) {
        $this->itemsTable[] = [
            'part_no' => '',
            'part_name' => '',
            'part_qty' => '',
            'part_price' => '',
            'part_subtotal' => '',
        ];
    } else {
        if($this->discountPrice == null) {
            $this->discountPrice = 0;
        } else {
            $this->includeDiscount = 1;
        }
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            $this->itemsTable[$key] = [
                'part_no' => strtoupper($value['part_no']),
                'part_name' => $value['part_name'],
                'part_qty' => $value['part_qty'],
                'part_price' => $value['part_price'],
                'part_subtotal' => $value['part_subtotal'],
            ];
        }
        $this->reCalculate();
    }
 }
  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.items-table');
  }
}
```

I've also tried `try .. catch` which seems that it does not catch anything during the presumed errneous code.

This is the view of the component of items-table:

```
<div>
<table class="order-list table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:5%">No.</th>
            <th>Part no.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Qty</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
            <th>Sum</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php
            $tabIndex = 1;
        @endphp
        @if(!empty($itemsTable))
            @foreach ($itemsTable as $index => $item)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $loop->index+1 }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="part_no[]" id="part_no{{ $index }}" class="form-control text-center" value="{{ $item['part_no'] }}" tabindex="{{ $tabIndex + 1 }}" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="part_name[]" id="" cols="30" rows="4" class="form-control" tabindex="{{ $tabIndex + 2 }}" wire:model.lazy="itemsTable.{{ $index }}.part_name" required>{{ $item['part_name'] }}</textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="part_qty[]" class="form-control" min="0" max="999999" value="{{ $item['part_qty'] }}" id="" wire:model.lazy="itemsTable.{{ $index }}.part_qty" wire:change="reCalculate" tabindex="{{ $tabIndex + 3 }}" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="part_price[]" class="form-control" min="0" max="999999" value="{{ $item['part_price'] }}" id="" wire:model.lazy="itemsTable.{{ $index }}.part_price" wire:change="reCalculate" tabindex="{{ $tabIndex + 4 }}" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="part_subtotal" disabled value="{{ $item['part_subtotal'] }}" wire:model="itemsTable.{{ $index }}.part_subtotal" class="form-control" tabindex="-1"/>
                </td>
                <td> <a href="" wire:click.prevent="deleteItem({{ $index }})" tabindex="-1"><i class="fas fa-times" style="color:red"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            @php
                $tabIndex += 4;
            @endphp
            @endforeach
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" wire:model.lazy="includeDiscount" wire:change="reCalculate" tabindex="-1" class="form-check-input" id="includeDiscount">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="includeDiscount">Discount?</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @if ($includeDiscount == 1)
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Subtotal: <strong>{{ $this->formatEur($subTotal) }}€</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Discount: <input type="number" class="form-control" name="discount_price" step="0.01" wire:model.lazy="discountPrice" id="discountPrice" wire:change="reCalculate" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Total: <strong style="font-size: 13pt">{{ $this->formatEur($totalPrice) }}€</strong></td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="text-center">
    <span style="display: none; color: red;" id="itemEmptyNotice">There's empty items.</span><br>
    <span style="display: none; color: red;" id="maxLengthLimit">Length limit reached.</span><br>
    <button wire:click.prevent="addRow" class="btn btn-primary text-white" tabindex="{{ $tabIndex + 5 }}">Add New Item</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.addEventListener('focus-new-partno', event => {
            $('#part_no'+event.detail.id).focus();
        });

        window.livewire.on('itemEmpty', () => {
            $('#itemEmptyNotice').show();
        });

        window.livewire.on('maxLengthLimit', () => {
            $('#maxLengthLimit').show();
        });

        window.addEventListener('discount-too-high', event => {
            $('#discountPrice').val(event.detail.maxDiscount);
        });

    });
</script>
</div>
```

This is the log from laravel (from the error 500) laravel.log:

```
[2021-11-23 09:39:10] production.ERROR: No application encryption key 

has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:101)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(263): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(103): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(82): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(34): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->parseKey(Array)
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(873): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#6 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array, true)
#7 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(694): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#8 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#9 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(1031): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#10 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(951): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#11 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(912): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#12 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#13 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array, true)
#14 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(694): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#15 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#16 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(156): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#17 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#21 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\DisableBrowserCache.php(19): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Livewire\\DisableBrowserCache->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-debugbar\\src\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php(36): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\public\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 {main}
"} 
[2021-11-23 09:39:10] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:101)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(263): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(103): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(82): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(34): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->parseKey(Array)
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(873): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#6 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array, true)
#7 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(694): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#8 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#9 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(1031): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#10 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(951): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#11 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(912): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#12 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#13 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array, true)
#14 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(694): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#15 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#16 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(206): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#17 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#18 C:\\laragon\\www\\domain\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#19 {main}
"}
```

Comment: maybe it´s typo in your post, but check the root div is closed properly

Comment: @Prospero Unfortunately, it was a (indentation) formatting issue that omitted the last closing </div> tag. It is already closed properly.

Comment: I am starting to suspect that it has to do with the data binding `wire:model`. I removed `lazy` and now error 500 appears much more often.

Comment: Since you have a _500 Internal Error_ it means the error is from PHP. Can you share the last log from **laravel.log**?

Comment: Also, I suspect that your content in `<script>` is ran every time your component update something from livewire. You can use `wire:ignore` to prevent this behavior

Comment: Hey @ClémentBaconnier, I just edited the post to include the result from `laravel.log`. I've also added `wire:ignore` to script and will monitor if the SyntaxError happens again.

Comment: `No application encryption key` means you need to run  `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239474/discussion-between-the-valo-and-clement-baconnier).

Answer (score -1):

Just run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Do not run this just if you have a "Unexpected token < in JSON and Internal Server Error 500" error.
The reason why this would resolve the author's issue is in his log files; he has "No application encryption key has been specified" None of the other comments above seem to address this, but it will almost always cause errors in your app.
The key is used for encrypted cookies, you can read more here: https://tighten.com/insights/app-key-and-you/